# Cant remove data from DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF app, with datagrid which I use for displaying data from database (Enitity Framework Core).
I want to add button for clearing the datagrid (remove all data). But all the options for removing don't work. What am I missing here?

```
dbContext.myData.Load();
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = dbContext.myData.Local.ToBindingList();
```

I press a button to call DataGrid clean

```
                myDataGrid.ItemsSource = null;
                myDataGrid.Columns.Clear();
                myDataGrid.Items.Clear();
                myDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
```

But nothing gets removed. Why is that?

Comment: Are you certain the button event is executed?

Comment: Yes, I tested to change button text when clicked, and it works.

Comment: What if you use Data Source instead of ItemSource

Comment: There is no DataSource in WPF. To use it I would need to rewrite the program for Windows Forms.

Comment: You are right. I should have done better than that :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should clear from both datagrid and database object.
you have done the data grid part, clear the database object too.
(didn't try but maybe setting itemsource to an empty new object also do the same)